# Creating Executable Jar with Ant Script Generated from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, ant

I export a runable jar file from my Java project in Eclipse and I check the "Save as Ant script" box and give it a location for the build.xml.

When I use the Ant script produced from the export, the jar file is built but it is almost twice the size as the jar file produced when I exported it from Eclipse directly.

I tried both running the Ant script from within Eclipse and from the command line with the same result.

From Eclipse the jar is 6.6M and using the script it is 10.6M

Eclipse 4.15.0
Ant 1.9.15

Comment: If adding `level="9"` into the Ant `<jar ...>` tag does not help, then look in both to see which files are in each.

Comment: Exporting implies creating an artifact which does not rely on Eclipse.  So, I expect the exported Ant build file creates a “fat jar” which includes all dependent libraries, as opposed to Eclipse where the libraries are left separate and are merely included in the classpath when you run the program.

Comment: When I export the jar from Eclipse I choose to "Extract required libraries into the generated jar."